# Custom Object detection app crashed/stops after uploading video file and converting it to images for detection (Android Studio)

Tags: java, android-studio

**Context:**

I used a template of an android app from https://github.com/pramod722445/Custom_Object_Detection_App
and added java files to detect images from a video. I trained the model on Google Colab and converted it to a tflite file and renamed it as `bline_model.tflite` with a text folder with the label `bline_label.txt` in Android Studio. When I run the application, it stops/crashes after the video to image phase is done. I think the error originates from either `objectDetectorClass.java` or `PreviewImageActivity.java`. How do I fix it?

***CODE***

*MainActivity.java*

```
package bline.detector.com.ffmpegvideoeditor.activity;

import android.Manifest;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.ContentUris;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.DocumentsContract;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.VideoView;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;

import com.github.hiteshsondhi88.libffmpeg.ExecuteBinaryResponseHandler;
import com.github.hiteshsondhi88.libffmpeg.FFmpeg;
import com.github.hiteshsondhi88.libffmpeg.LoadBinaryResponseHandler;
import com.github.hiteshsondhi88.libffmpeg.exceptions.FFmpegCommandAlreadyRunningException;
import com.github.hiteshsondhi88.libffmpeg.exceptions.FFmpegNotSupportedException;

import org.florescu.android.rangeseekbar.RangeSeekBar;
import org.opencv.android.OpenCVLoader;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import bline.detector.com.ffmpegvideoeditor.R;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    static {
        if (!OpenCVLoader.initDebug())
            Log.d("ERROR", "Unable to load OpenCV");
        else
            Log.d("SUCCESS", "OpenCV loaded");
    }

    private Button uploadVideo;
    private Button extractImages;
    private VideoView videoView;
    private String filePath;
    private static final String FILEPATH = "filepath";
    private Uri selectedVideoUri;
    private FFmpeg ffmpeg;
    private static final int REQUEST_TAKE_GALLERY_VIDEO = 100;
    private static final String TAG = "amirah";
    private int choice = 0;
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    private RangeSeekBar rangeSeekBar;
    private Context mContext;




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mContext = this;

        uploadVideo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.uploadVideo);
        extractImages = (Button) findViewById(R.id.extractImages);

        videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView);
        rangeSeekBar = (RangeSeekBar) findViewById(R.id.rangeSeekBar);


        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        progressDialog.setTitle(null);
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        rangeSeekBar.setEnabled(false);
        loadFFMpegBinary();

        uploadVideo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23)
                    getPermission();
                else
                    uploadVideo();

            }
        });

        extractImages.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                choice = 1;

                if (selectedVideoUri != null) {
                    extractImagesVideo(rangeSeekBar.getSelectedMinValue().intValue() * 1000, rangeSeekBar.getSelectedMaxValue().intValue() * 1000);
                } else
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please Upload a Video", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        });
    }

    private void getPermission() {
        String[] params = null;
        String writeExternalStorage = Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE;
        String readExternalStorage = Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE;

        int hasWriteExternalStoragePermission = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, writeExternalStorage);
        int hasReadExternalStoragePermission = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, readExternalStorage);
        List<String> permissions = new ArrayList<String>();

        if (hasWriteExternalStoragePermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
            permissions.add(writeExternalStorage);
        if (hasReadExternalStoragePermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
            permissions.add(readExternalStorage);

        if (!permissions.isEmpty()) {
            params = permissions.toArray(new String[permissions.size()]);
        }
        if (params != null && params.length > 0) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                    params,
                    100);
        } else
            uploadVideo();
    }

    /**
     * Handling response for permission request
     */
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                           String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        switch (requestCode) {
            case 100: {

                if (grantResults.length > 0
                        && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    uploadVideo();
                }
            }
            break;
        }
    }


    private void uploadVideo() {
        try {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setType("video/*");
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Video"), REQUEST_TAKE_GALLERY_VIDEO);
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == REQUEST_TAKE_GALLERY_VIDEO) {
                selectedVideoUri = data.getData();
                videoView.setVideoURI(selectedVideoUri);
                videoView.start();
            }
        }
    }

    private void loadFFMpegBinary() {
        try {
            if (ffmpeg == null) {
                ffmpeg = FFmpeg.getInstance(this);
            }
            ffmpeg.loadBinary(new LoadBinaryResponseHandler() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure() { showUnsupportedExceptionDialog();
                }

                @Override
                public void onSuccess() {
                    Log.d(TAG, "ffmpeg: successfully Loaded");
                }
            });
        } catch (FFmpegNotSupportedException e) {
            showUnsupportedExceptionDialog();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "exception: " + e);
        }
    }

    private void showUnsupportedExceptionDialog() {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                .setTitle("Not Supported")
                .setMessage("Device Not Supported")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        MainActivity.this.finish();
                    }
                })
                .create()
                .show();

    }

    private void extractImagesVideo(int startMs, int endMs) {
        File moviesDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES
        );

        String filePrefix = "extract_picture";
        String fileExtn = ".jpg";
        String yourRealPath = getPath(MainActivity.this, selectedVideoUri);

        File dir = new File(moviesDir, "VideoEditor");
        int fileNo = 0;
        while (dir.exists()) {
            fileNo++;
            dir = new File(moviesDir, "VideoEditor" + fileNo);

        }
        dir.mkdir();
        filePath = dir.getAbsolutePath();
        File dest = new File(dir, filePrefix + "%03d" + fileExtn);


        Log.d(TAG, "startTrim: src: " + yourRealPath);
        Log.d(TAG, "startTrim: dest: " + dest.getAbsolutePath());

        String[] complexCommand = {"-y", "-i", yourRealPath, "-an", "-r", "1", "-ss", "" + startMs / 1000, "-t", "" + (endMs - startMs) / 1000, dest.getAbsolutePath()};
        execFFmpegBinary(complexCommand);
    }
    //-y overwrite output files without asking
    //-i ffmpeg reads from an arbitrary number of input "files" specified by the -i option
    //-an disable audio recordings
    //-r 1/2 will extract one image frame from every 2 second of video
    //-r 1/2 will extract one image frame from every 2 second of video.Similarly, -r 1 will extract one image frame from every second of the video.
    //remove -r option if u want to extract all video frames as images from the specified time duration
    //-ss seeks to position
    //-t limit the duration of data read from the input file

    private void execFFmpegBinary(final String[] command) {
        try {
            ffmpeg.execute(command, new ExecuteBinaryResponseHandler() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(String message) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "FAILED with output: " + message);
                }

                @Override
                public void onSuccess(String s) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "SUCCESS with output: " + s);
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, PreviewImageActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra(FILEPATH, filePath);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }


                @Override
                public void onProgress(String s) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Started command : ffmpeg " + command);
                    if (choice == 1)
                        progressDialog.setMessage("progress: " + s);
                    Log.d(TAG, "progress : " + s);
                }

                @Override
                public void onStart() {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Started command : ffmpeg " + command);
                    progressDialog.setMessage("Processing...");
                    progressDialog.show();
                }

                @Override
                public void onFinish() {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Finished command : ffmpeg " + command);
                    if (choice == 1) {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                    }

                }
            });
        } catch (FFmpegCommandAlreadyRunningException e) {
            // do nothing for now
        }
    }

    public static boolean deleteDir(File dir) {
        if (dir.isDirectory()) {
            String[] children = dir.list();
            if (children != null) {
                for (int i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
                    boolean success = deleteDir(new File(dir, children[i]));
                    if (!success) {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return dir.delete();
    }

    private String getPath(final Context context, final Uri uri) {

        final boolean isKitKat = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT;

        // DocumentProvider
        if (isKitKat && DocumentsContract.isDocumentUri(context, uri)) {
            // ExternalStorageProvider
            if (isExternalStorageDocument(uri)) {
                final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                final String[] split = docId.split(":");
                final String type = split[0];

                if ("primary".equalsIgnoreCase(type)) {
                    return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + split[1];
                }

            }
            // DownloadsProvider
            else if (isDownloadsDocument(uri)) {

                final String id = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                final Uri contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                        Uri.parse("content://downloads/public_downloads"), Long.valueOf(id));

                return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, null, null);
            }
            // MediaProvider
            else if (isMediaDocument(uri)) {
                final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                final String[] split = docId.split(":");
                final String type = split[0];

                Uri contentUri = null;
                if ("image".equals(type)) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                } else if ("video".equals(type)) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                }

                final String selection = "_id=?";
                final String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{
                        split[1]
                };

                return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, selection, selectionArgs);
            }
        }
        // MediaStore (and general)
        else if ("content".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
            return getDataColumn(context, uri, null, null);
        }
        // File
        else if ("file".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
            return uri.getPath();
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Get the value of the data column for this Uri.
     */
    private String getDataColumn(Context context, Uri uri, String selection,
                                 String[] selectionArgs) {

        Cursor cursor = null;
        final String column = "_data";
        final String[] projection = {
                column
        };

        try {
            cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs,
                    null);
            if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                final int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(column);
                return cursor.getString(column_index);
            }
        } finally {
            if (cursor != null)
                cursor.close();
        }
        return null;
    }

    private boolean isMediaDocument(Uri uri) {
        return "com.android.providers.media.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }

    private boolean isDownloadsDocument(Uri uri) {
        return "com.android.providers.downloads.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }

    private boolean isExternalStorageDocument(Uri uri) {
        return "com.android.externalstorage.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }

}
```

*objectDetectorClass.java*

```
package bline.detector.com.ffmpegvideoeditor.activity;

import android.content.res.AssetFileDescriptor;
import android.content.res.AssetManager;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;

import org.opencv.android.Utils;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;
import org.opencv.core.Point;
import org.opencv.core.Scalar;
import org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc;
import org.tensorflow.lite.Interpreter;
import org.tensorflow.lite.gpu.GpuDelegate;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.ByteOrder;
import java.nio.channels.FileChannel;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.TreeMap;

public class objectDetectorClass {

    // used to load model and predict
    private Interpreter interpreter;
    // store all label in array
    private List<String> labelList;
    private int INPUT_SIZE;
    private int PIXEL_SIZE=3; // for RGB
    private int IMAGE_MEAN=0;
    private  float IMAGE_STD=255.0f;
    // use to initialize gpu in app
    private GpuDelegate gpuDelegate;
    private int height=0;
    private  int width=0;

    objectDetectorClass(AssetManager assetManager,String modelPath, String labelPath,int inputSize) throws IOException{
        INPUT_SIZE=inputSize;
        // use to define gpu or cpu // no. of threads
        Interpreter.Options options=new Interpreter.Options();
        gpuDelegate=new GpuDelegate();
        options.addDelegate(gpuDelegate);
        options.setNumThreads(4); // set it according to your phone
        // loading model
        interpreter=new Interpreter(loadModelFile(assetManager,modelPath),options);
        // load labelmap
        labelList=loadLabelList(assetManager,labelPath);


    }

    private List<String> loadLabelList(AssetManager assetManager, String labelPath) throws IOException {
        // to store label
        List<String> labelList=new ArrayList<>();
        // create a new reader
        BufferedReader reader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(assetManager.open(labelPath)));
        String line;
        // loop through each line and store it to labelList
        while ((line=reader.readLine())!=null){
            labelList.add(line);
        }
        reader.close();
        return labelList;
    }

    private ByteBuffer loadModelFile(AssetManager assetManager, String modelPath) throws IOException {
        // use to get description of file
        AssetFileDescriptor fileDescriptor=assetManager.openFd(modelPath);
        FileInputStream inputStream=new FileInputStream(fileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor());
        FileChannel fileChannel=inputStream.getChannel();
        long startOffset =fileDescriptor.getStartOffset();
        long declaredLength=fileDescriptor.getDeclaredLength();

        return fileChannel.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY,startOffset,declaredLength);
    }

    public Mat recognizeVideo(Mat mat_image){

        Bitmap bitmap=null;
        bitmap=Bitmap.createBitmap(mat_image.cols(),mat_image.rows(),Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Utils.matToBitmap(mat_image,bitmap);
        height=bitmap.getHeight();
        width=bitmap.getWidth();

        // scale the bitmap to input size of model
        Bitmap scaledBitmap=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap,INPUT_SIZE,INPUT_SIZE,false);

        // convert bitmap to bytebuffer as model input should be in it
        ByteBuffer byteBuffer=convertBitmapToByteBuffer(scaledBitmap);

        // defining output
        Object[] input=new Object[1];
        input[0]=byteBuffer;

        Map<Integer,Object> output_map=new TreeMap<>();
        // create treemap of three array (boxes,score,classes)

        float[][][]boxes =new float[1][10][4];
        // 10: top 10 objects detected
        // 4: coordinates in image
        float[][] scores=new float[1][10];
        // stores scores of 10 object
        float[][] classes=new float[1][10];
        // stores class of object

        // add it to object_map;
        output_map.put(0,boxes);
        output_map.put(1,classes);
        output_map.put(2,scores);

        // now predict
        interpreter.runForMultipleInputsOutputs(input,output_map);

        Object value=output_map.get(0);
        Object Object_class=output_map.get(1);
        Object score=output_map.get(2);

        // loop through each object
        // as output has only 10 boxes
        for (int i=0;i<10;i++){
            float class_value=(float) Array.get(Array.get(Object_class,0),i);
            float score_value=(float) Array.get(Array.get(score,0),i);
            // define threshold for score

            // Here you can change threshold according to your model
            if(score_value>0.8){
                Object box1=Array.get(Array.get(value,0),i);

                // multiply it with Original height and width of frame
                float top=(float) Array.get(box1,0)*height;
                float left=(float) Array.get(box1,1)*width;
                float bottom=(float) Array.get(box1,2)*height;
                float right=(float) Array.get(box1,3)*width;
                // draw rectangle in Original frame // starting point  //ending point of box  //color of box        thickness
                Imgproc.rectangle(mat_image,new Point(left,top),new Point(right,bottom),new Scalar(0, 255, 0, 255),2);
                // write text on frame
                // string of class name of object  // starting point                         // color of text           // size of text
                Imgproc.putText(mat_image,labelList.get((int) class_value),new Point(left,top),3,1,new Scalar(255, 0, 0, 255),2);
            }
        }

        return mat_image;
    }

    private ByteBuffer convertBitmapToByteBuffer(Bitmap bitmap) {
        ByteBuffer byteBuffer;
        int quant=1;
        int size_images=INPUT_SIZE;
        if(quant==0){
            byteBuffer=ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(1*size_images*size_images*3);
        }
        else {
            byteBuffer=ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(4*1*size_images*size_images*3);
        }
        byteBuffer.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        int[] intValues=new int[size_images*size_images];
        bitmap.getPixels(intValues,0,bitmap.getWidth(),0,0,bitmap.getWidth(),bitmap.getHeight());
        int pixel=0;

        for (int i=0;i<size_images;++i){
            for (int j=0;j<size_images;++j){
                final  int val=intValues[pixel++];
                if(quant==0){
                    byteBuffer.put((byte) ((val>>16)&0xFF));
                    byteBuffer.put((byte) ((val>>8)&0xFF));
                    byteBuffer.put((byte) (val&0xFF));
                }
                else {
                    byteBuffer.putFloat((((val >> 16) & 0xFF))/255.0f);
                    byteBuffer.putFloat((((val >> 8) & 0xFF))/255.0f);
                    byteBuffer.putFloat((((val) & 0xFF))/255.0f);
                }
            }
        }
        return byteBuffer;
    }
}
```

*PreviewImageActivity.java*

```
package bline.detector.com.ffmpegvideoeditor.activity;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageSwitcher;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.ViewSwitcher;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import org.opencv.android.Utils;
import org.opencv.core.CvType;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import bline.detector.com.ffmpegvideoeditor.R;

public class PreviewImageActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String FILEPATH = "filepath";
    private objectDetectorClass objectDetectorClass;
    private ImageSwitcher imageSwitcher;
    private Button prev;
    private Button next;
    int placement = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_preview_image);
        TextView tvInstruction = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvInstruction);
        imageSwitcher = (ImageSwitcher) findViewById(R.id.imageSwitcher);

        prev = findViewById(R.id.prev);
        next = findViewById(R.id.next);

        ArrayList<Bitmap> bitmap = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();
        ArrayList<Bitmap> bitmaps = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();
        ArrayList<Drawable> drawables = new ArrayList<Drawable>();

        try {
            objectDetectorClass = new objectDetectorClass(getAssets(), "bline_model.tflite", "bline_label.txt", 300);
            Log.d("PreviewImageActivity", "Model is successfully loaded");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d("PreviewImageActivity", "Getting some error");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        imageSwitcher.setFactory(new ViewSwitcher.ViewFactory() {
            @Override
            public View makeView() {
                ImageView imageView = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
                imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
                return imageView;
            }
        });

        prev.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (placement > 0) {
                    placement--;
                    imageSwitcher.setImageDrawable(drawables.get(placement));
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(PreviewImageActivity.this, "No Previous Images", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });

        next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (placement < drawables.size() - 1) {
                    placement++;
                    imageSwitcher.setImageDrawable(drawables.get(placement));
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(PreviewImageActivity.this, "No More Images", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });

        String filePath = getIntent().getStringExtra(FILEPATH);
        ArrayList<String> f = new ArrayList<String>();

        File dir = new File(filePath);
        tvInstruction.setText("Images stored at path " + filePath);

        File[] listFile;
        listFile = dir.listFiles();

        for (File e : listFile) {
            f.add(e.getAbsolutePath());
        }

        if (f != null) {
            Log.d("PreviewImageAdapter", "filepath: " + f);
            for (int position = 0; position < f.size(); position++) {
                Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f.get(position));
                bitmap.add(bmp);
                Log.d("PreviewImageAdapter", "bitmap: " + bitmap);

                if (bitmap.size() == f.size()) {
                    for (int m = 0; m < bitmap.size(); m++) {
                        Mat selected_image = new Mat(bitmap.get(m).getHeight(), bitmap.get(m).getWidth(), CvType.CV_8UC4);
                        Utils.bitmapToMat(bitmap.get(m), selected_image);
                        selected_image = objectDetectorClass.recognizeVideo(selected_image);
                        Bitmap bitmap1 = Bitmap.createBitmap(selected_image.cols(), selected_image.rows(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
                        Utils.matToBitmap(selected_image, bitmap1);
                        bitmaps.add(bitmap1);
                        Log.d("PreviewImageAdapter", "detected images: " + bitmaps);
                    }

                    if (bitmaps.size() == bitmap.size()) {
                        for (int n = 0; n < bitmaps.size(); n++) {
                            Drawable drawable = new BitmapDrawable(bitmaps.get(n));
                            drawables.add(drawable);
                            Log.d("PreviewImageAdapter", "drawables: " + drawables);
                        }
                    }
                    imageSwitcher.setImageDrawable(drawables.get(0));
                    placement = 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am also new to java and am sorry if my question is silly.